# Fitting text into a listView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-4.5

I want to create a listView that shows users nicknames for a chat program. For that I created a new class that inherits from listViewItem.

What i want to do is, depending on the length of the **nickname scale** my font size.
I have read lots of articles about scaling but **ALL** of them depend on a **graphics object** and i have no clue how i get one of those ??? i tried it with a label and there it would be from the paint event but listView doesnt have such an event? so how do i scale this font ?

**Q:**

How do I get the right fontsize that the Nickname will fit into a specified rectangle ?

EDIT: Forgot to say I'm completly new to anything with grafic stuff i only used the Designer and set some properties.

Comment: Have you tried something, measuring a string using Graphics and different fonts, getting the cell width etc.?

Comment: Im sorry i have no clue about anything with Graphics so no i have not

Comment: You can get a Graphics object for measuring a Font by `Graphics G = anycontrolsEGYourListview.CreateGraphics()`. You need to use `using` or `Dispose` of it later. What `View` mode do you set you `ListView` to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `OwnerDraw` property of the `ListView` to `true`, add draw item event handler like this:

```
listView1.DrawItem += listView1_DrawItem;
```

And here is a simple implementation of what you want so you can play with and tune it up:

```
void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
     float emSize = e.Item.Font.Size;
     Font font = new Font(e.Item.Font.FontFamily, emSize);
     while(e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font).Width>e.Item.Bounds.Width)
     {
          emSize--;
          font = new Font(e.Item.Font.FontFamily, emSize);
          e.Item.Font = font;
     }
     e.DrawText();
}
```

You see that you need to change the font size and measure the string you want to display so it fits in the cell completely. Presuming that if your current font size doesn't fit, you want to make it smaller.

Comment: The only problem now is that it blanks out my column header and the images i want to display next to the text are gone too

Answer (score 0):

I marked @Nikola answer right because it explained a lot but in my case i needed something way simpler and thanks to @TaW i also got the problem with the Graphics solved here my code snippet

```
public static Font getNewFont(Font origFont, string text, float maxWidth, Graphics g)
    {

        float emSize = origFont.Size;
        Font font = origFont;

        while (g.MeasureString(text, font).Width > maxWidth)
        {
            emSize--;
            font = new Font(origFont.FontFamily, emSize);
        }

        return font;
    }
```